# DataGrid not displaying, ListView works fine?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

Think I'm missing something pretty simple here, but I can't seem to get my Datagrid to properly display?

I was originally using a ListView to display some tabular data, but I wanted to autosize the columns and so I switched over to a DataGrid using DataGridTextColumns and now I get nothing.  The correct number of rows appears in the grid, but each cell appears to be blank.  Any ideas?

Here's my XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Charges}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Count" Binding="{Binding Count, Mode=OneWay}" Width="SizeToCells" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Charge" Binding="{Binding LawId, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource LawConverter}}" Width="SizeToCells" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Incident Date" Binding="{Binding IncidentDate, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}" Width="SizeToCells" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Convicted" Binding="{Binding IsConvicted, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Disposition" Binding="{Binding ChargeDispositionCodeId, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource CodeConverter}, ConverterParameter='ChargeDispositionCode'}" Width="SizeToCells" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Disposition Date" Binding="{Binding DispositionDate, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}" Width="SizeToCells" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**
This xaml DOES work and displays correctly, but I'd like the columns to autosize and so a DataGrid would be preferable:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Charges}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Count" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Count, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Charge" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LawId, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource LawConverter}}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Incident Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IncidentDate, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Convicted" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IsConvicted, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Disposition" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ChargeDispositionCodeId, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource CodeConverter}, ConverterParameter='ChargeDispositionCode'}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Disposition Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DispositionDate, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I suspect you should turn AutoGenerateColumns off if you manually specify the columns.

Comment: Oops... copy-and-paste strikes again.  It was something I was messing with in order to try to get it to work.  Turned off now, but no difference.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the text for the cells has the same `Background` as `Foreground`. If you enter edit mode for a cell, does it still seem empty?

Comment: It's displaying inside of a FlowDocument, so there is no editing.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Output debugger window when your grid is initialized.  Do you get any Binding error messages?

You also need to turn off "AutoGenerateColumns" since you are explicitly defining the columns in your XAML.